# labeling tkinter buttons with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I have a simple for loop that creates two rows of three buttons in a window

```
for c in range(3):
    for r in range(2):
        tk.Button(width=10, height=2).grid(column=c, row=r, pady=6, padx=2)
```

I've been trying to label each individual button with text taken from each row in a pandas dataframe like so

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('255x200')
data = {'name': ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name4', 'Name5', 'Name6'],
        'Value': ['Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4', 'Value5', 'Value6']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
index = df.index
rows = len(index)
namelist = df.iloc[1:rows,0]
for c in range(3):
    for r in range(2):
        for t in namelist:
            tk.Button(width=10, height=2, text=t).grid(column=c, row=r, pady=6, padx=2)
window.mainloop()
```

the issue this causes is that every button is labeled with the latest entry in the 'Name' column. is there a way to properly label these buttons using this for loop?

Comment: You are looping through by the number of columns, rows, and number of elements in namelist. So you are actually going through the loop (2*3*6) times, not (2*3). You should handle the number of rows and columns a separate way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your looping method. You are looping through the row and column numbers and then by each name in the namelist. Essentially what is happening is for each row and column, you then loop through each name in namelist. This means you are creating 36 buttons instead of 6.

Lets look at `r=0` and `c=0`. In `r=0` and `c=0` you then loop through all names in namelist. First, in the grid `(0,0)` you place the button `Name1`. However, then you place another button in grid `(0,0)` with the label `Name2` that overlaps it, so you only see `Name2`. This continues until you reach `Name6`. This is why you only see `Name6` in each location.

Also, don't forget to index starting with 0 in `namelist = df.iloc[0:rows,0]`. Alternatively you could set `namelist=df['name']`, then you don't need to calculate the rows.

One solution is to loop through the namelist only and use separate counters inside the loop for the rows and columns that you manually increment.

Try this. I edited the loop so you only loop through each name once.

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('255x200')
data = {'name': ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name4', 'Name5', 'Name6'],
        'Value': ['Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4', 'Value5', 'Value6']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
index = df.index
rows = len(index)
namelist = df.iloc[0:rows,0]
c = 0
r = 0
for t in namelist:
    tk.Button(width=10, height=2, text=t).grid(column=c, row=r, pady=6, padx=2)
    c = c + 1
    if c > 2:
        c = 0
        r = r + 1
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy task. You can do it very sophisticated with variables variables to assign a variable to your buttons or like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd


window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('255x200')

data = {'name': ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name4', 'Name5', 'Name6'],
        'Value': ['Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4', 'Value5', 'Value6']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
index = df.index
rows = len(index)
namelist = df.iloc[0:rows,0]

for r in range(2):
    for c in range(3):
        idx_namelist = (((r+1)*(r+1)+c)-1)
        tk.Button(width=10, height=2, text=namelist.iloc[idx_namelist]).grid(column=c, row=r, pady=6, padx=2)
window.mainloop()
```

Your code had an error in here. It should start at 0:

> namelist = df.iloc[1:rows,0]

And your button got always the name of the last value of the loop, because `text=`never changed.

I changed c and r and used them to calculate the number of the button and used this index to get the name for the button.
`idx_namelist = (((r+1)*(r+1)+c)-1)` does the trick.